# NSMutableArray not showing first value

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have a picker where its values are populated from the database(using NSMutableArray), the problem is that I'm trying to add a NSString value to index 0 of my picker(or of the NSMutableArray) but nothing is showing just a blank space in that position(position 0) and below it the other values from the database are shown like this(assuming its my picker):

```
------------------------

------------------------
Mouse
------------------------
Keyboard
------------------------
Motherboard
------------------------
```

this is my code that I use to retrieve the data from the database:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getProducts
{
    NSMutableArray *products = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Products *all = [[Products alloc]init];
    NSString allstring= @"All";
    all.all= allstring; // the "all" is a NSString type variable declared in Products class
    [products addObject:all];

    NSMutableArray *newadditions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableIndexSet *indexes =[NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];
    [indexes addIndex:2];
    [indexes addIndex:3];
    const char* sql = "SELECT ID,Name \
    FROM Products";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);

    if(sqlResult == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            int i=0;
            Products *product =[[Products alloc]init];

            char*name = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);

            product.name = (name)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name]: @"";

            [newadditions insertObject:product atIndex:i];
            i++;

        }


        [products insertObjects:newadditions atIndexes:indexes];


        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with the database");
        NSLog(@"%d",sqlResult);
    }
    return products;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

**This is my Products.h**

```
@interface Products : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    NSString *all;
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *all;
@end
```

**Products.m:**

```
#import "Products.h"

@implementation Products

@synthesize name;
@synthesize all;

@end
```

**and where I call the picker:**

```
@interface ViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PRLabel *namesLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView* namesPicker;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *namesAll;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.namesPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    self.namesPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.namesPicker.delegate = self;
    self.namesPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    self.namesLabel.inputView = [self namesPicker];
    self.namesLabel.inputAccessoryView = [self accessoryToolbar];


    DBAccess *dbAccess = [[DBAccess alloc]init];
    self.namesAll = [dbAccess getProducts];

    [dbAccess closeDatabase];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}



#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        return [self.namesAll count];


}

#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDelegate

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        Products * prod = [self.namesAll objectAtIndex:row];
        return prod.type;


}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        self.namesLabel.text = [self.namesPicker.delegate pickerView:pickerView titleForRow:row forComponent:component];



}

@end
```

**EDIT AGAIN:**

**the getProducts before I try to add "All" string to first position of array:**

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getProducts
{
    NSMutableArray *products = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    const char* sql = "SELECT ID,Name \
    FROM Products ";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);

    if(sqlResult == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            Product *product =[[Product alloc]init];

            char*name = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);

            product.name = (name)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name]: @"";

            [products addObject:product];

        }

         NSLog(@"%@",products);
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with the database");
        NSLog(@"%d",sqlResult);
    }
    return products;
}
```

**LOG:**

```
2013-07-24 13:49:56.425 just[1401:c07] Opening Database
2013-07-24 13:49:56.433 just[1401:c07] (
    All,
    "<Product: 0x719f350>",
    "<Product: 0x719fcb0>",
    "<Product: 0x719ff30>"
)

2013-07-24 13:49:58.053 just[1401:c07] -[__NSCFConstantString name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd938
2013-07-24 13:49:58.054 just[1401:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd938'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x20a1012 0x11aee7e 0x212c4bd 0x2090bbc 0x209094e 0x6a06 0xeb6fc 0xee886 0x1ad8fb 0x1ad9cf 0x1961bb 0x194872 0x19f5d4 0x52e299 0xed27a 0xed10c 0x1432dd 0x11c26b0 0x269dfc0 0x269233c 0x269deaf 0x4a23fe 0x49b798 0x49ca34 0x49e8a2 0x49e931 0x49e97b 0x498117 0x201386 0x200e29 0x2935 0x125cef 0x125f02 0x103d4a 0xf5698 0x1ffcdf9 0x1ffcad0 0x2016bf5 0x2016962 0x2047bb6 0x2046f44 0x2046e1b 0x1ffb7e3 0x1ffb668 0xf2ffc 0x250d 0x2435)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Comment: I guess because you are not setting the name of the "all" product.  It woud be helpful to show where you actually *use* this array.

Comment: can you post the log for your array

Comment: can you share picker's datasource code?

Comment: -1 for not reading the documentation.

Comment: @HotLicks just so that you know I read the documentation and doing exactly what is stated but inserting at index 0 is throwing an exception so I used two arrays just like the example in the documentation!

Comment: Insert at index 0 will only throw an exception if you try to insert a nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `all.all` to `all.name`, and t should work.

As a comment, your code is not very readable. The naming of variables is confusing and the use of indexes is scary. There's no need for a newadditions collection if you can do `addObject:` for each record you read.

Comment: yes thank you. It wasn't supposed to be like that but what I wanted to is add the string "All" to the first index of the array I stored my database values in. and I read that I cannot insert at the first position of an already populated array?

Comment: is there anyway I can add the string "All" to the array at position 0?

Comment: insertObject:AtIndex:0. ...geez read the sdk people...  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I tried it throws an exception! 2013-07-24 13:49:58.053 just[1401:c07] -[__NSCFConstantString type]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd938
2013-07-24 13:49:58.054 just[1401:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd938'

Comment: Show us the statements

Comment: in the getProducts that I wrote after the edit (the one before I try to add "All") I wrote this code after the while statement and it threw the exception: NSString *allString = @"All"; [products insertObject:allString AtIndext:0];

Comment: Nonono you cannot mix NSStrings with Products in that collection. The picker will crash trying to get the .name value, just insert a dummy product. Just like i said in the start of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The picker cannot show a random object, but a only a string (in its base configuration). Make sure you add the `name` or some other string attribute of your Products class to the array, (or instruct your picker's datasource to use the right field).

You should really change some names of your classes and variables. If one instance of your class represents a product, the class name should be `Product` not `Products`. Also, to use a property name like `all` is really not intuitive - try to think of something more generic and descriptive.

Also, in your for loop you set `i` to `0`, use it once and then increase it at the end of the loop. Why? Your index set code can also be eliminated.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to be like that but what I wanted to is add the string "All" to the first index of the array I stored my database values in. and I read that I cannot insert at the first position of an already populated array?

Comment: Sure you can. You can use `[array insertObject:id atIndex:0]`

Comment: In the datasource, always pass a string!